# How can I compile Rust code to run on a Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi2

I recently acquired a Raspberry PI 2 and I want to run a Rust program on it.

Is there a guide/instructions how to cross compile Rust programs on Raspberry PI 2? I've heard about running Rust on RPi or Arduino, although not recently.

I want a `Hello World` equivalent Rust program running on Raspberry Pi 2. It doesn't have to be a literal Hello World program, just something that is of similar low complexity.

Comment: Some useful links: http://metaverse.fr/blog/compiling-rust-for-the-raspberry-pi/ and https://github.com/npryce/rusty-pi/blob/master/doc/compile-the-compiler.asciidoc

Comment: Do you wish to *run* `rustc` on the RPi, or to you simply want to cross-compile a program that will execute on the RPi?

Comment: @Shepmaster I want to cross-compile program to execute on RPi2. I want to run something simple on it.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves How compatible is RPi with RPi2? That seems like a decent answer.

Comment: @DanielFath Honestly, I have no idea. I came up with those links after a quick google search. I will try and look into this later today if I have the chance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We have [rustup](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/05/13/rustup.html) now.

```
$ rustup target add arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ echo '[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]' >> ~/.cargo/config
$ echo 'linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"' >> ~/.cargo/config
$ cd <project dir>
$ cargo build --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I just had to add the missing quote-escapes (`"linker = \"arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc\""`). Would you mind to update your answer?

Comment: This answer works fine on Raspberry Pi 2s and 3s, but not on 1s or Zeros.
See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087233/291228) for a setup that builds binaries that work across all Pi versions.

Comment: I had to use `sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf libc6-dev-armhf-cross libc6-dev-armhf-cross binutils-doc gcc-7-locales cpp-doc gcc-7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-7-doc libgcc1-dbg-armhf-cross` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Instructions worked as written on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 9):

The Rust compiler is not distributed as a cross-compiler for the Raspberry Pi, so it needs to be compiled as a cross compiler with rpi dev tools.

1. Get rpi dev tools - `git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git ~/pi-tools`
2. get rust compiler from mozilla git repo and add rpi tools to the path `export PATH=~/pi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin:$PATH`
3. Look for rusty-pi dir on your home `./configure --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=$HOME/rusty-pi && make && make install`
4. Considering helloworld.rs -> `% ~/pi-rust/bin/rustc --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -C linker=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ helloworld.rs`

It will produce an executable.

Answer (score 9):

[@kazhik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412427/291228) will work for Raspberry Pi 2s and 3s (which are [ARMv7/8 based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications)), but not for Raspberry Pi 1s or Zeros (which are [ARMv6 based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications)).

The problem is that Debian/Ubuntu's `armhf` port (and thus their `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` package/compiler/toolchain) targets >= [ARMv7](https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/#status).

Fortunately, rustup's `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` targets >= [ARMv6](https://forge.rust-lang.org/platform-support.html#tier-2) (with hardware floating-point, which all Raspberry Pis support), so all that's needed is the correct linker.  The Raspberry Pi foundation provides one of those in their [tools repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools).

Putting it together, the following steps can be used to cross compile a Rust binary that works on all Raspberry Pis:

```
$ rustup target add arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
$ git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools raspberrypi-tools
$ echo "[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]" >> ~/.cargo/config
$ echo "linker = \"$(pwd)/raspberrypi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc\"" >> ~/.cargo/config
```

To test the cross-compiler (assuming a Pi is running and reachable with the default `raspberrypi` hostname):

```
cpick@devhost:  $ cargo new --bin rpi-test
cpick@devhost:  $ cd rpi-test
cpick@devhost:  $ cargo build --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
cpick@devhost:  $ scp target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/rpi-test pi@raspberrypi:
cpick@devhost:  $ ssh pi@raspberrypi
pi@raspberrypi: $ ./rpi-test
Hello, world!
```