# "linking with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc failed" when cross-compiling a Rust application from macOS to a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, rust

I want to cross-compile my Rust application on macOS to a Raspberry Pi 2. I searched a lot, but did not find a working solution. The last solution I tried was following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917513/how-can-i-compile-rust-code-to-run-on-a-raspberry-pi-2), but I couldn't get it to work.

- macOS version: 10.13.5 (High Sierra)
- rustup version: 1.11.0
- cargo version: 1.26.0

What I did:

- I cloned  [raspberrypi/tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools)
- Installed **arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf** and
  **armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf** toolchains via rustup
- Created `.cargo/config` file in the root of my project with following content

  ```
  [target.armv-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
  linker = "/Users/user/Documents/Programming/RustProjects/hello-pi/../../Utils/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
  ```
- Then I run `cargo build --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`

I get the following error:

```
linking with /Users/user/Documents/Programming/RustProjects/hello-pi/../../Utils/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc failed: exit code: 126
....
cannot execute binary file
```

It seems that I cannot run the `...gcc` binary on my macOS machine. What would be the right way to cross-compile my Rust application from macOS to the ARM architecture for a Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: The tools from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools are compiled for Linux and can only be run from Linux. You'll likely need to build the cross-compiler yourself.

Comment: I didn't know that before, thanks for clarifying. So essentially I need to compile `/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` for Mac OS ? And then use my personal compiled version as the linker ? So maybe use something like [crosstool-ng](https://github.com/crosstool-ng) ?

Answer (score 3):

`rust-std` library relies on `glibc` for things like `syscalls` and other low-level stuff, in order to cross-compile a Rust binary, one needs the appropriate C toolchain to be present as well. And this is where [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/introduction/) comes into play.

`crosstool-NG` is in the toolchain building business. You’re going to use it to build yourself a toolchain for linking against ARMv7-compatible `glibc`, which will in turn allow you to successfully build your Rust binary for the Pi.

- Clone the repo to a good location and bootstrap it:

```sh
cd /Users/USER
git clone https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng
cd crosstool-ng
./bootstrap
```

- Configure the installation and run it. To set where the tool goes on install,  run:

```sh
./configure --prefix=$PWD
make
make install
export PATH="${PATH}:${PWD}/bin"
```

If all things went as expected, you should be able to run `ct-ng version` and verify the tool’s ready to go.

- Configure the tool to build your `ARMv7 toolchain`. Luckily, crosstool-NG comes with some preset configurations, namely `armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf`. Run:

```sh
ct-ng armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf
```

There should be some output indicating that it’s now configured for `armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf`. You just need to tell ct-ng where the toolchain ought to go:

```sh
mkdir /Users/USER/ct-ng-toolchains
cd /Users/USER/ct-ng-toolchains
ct-ng menuconfig
```

It can be overwhelming, as there are a ton of options, but stick to the `Paths and misc options ---> menu option`. Highlight it and hit Enter.

Under `*** crosstool-NG behavior ***`, scroll down until you see this long string:
`(${CT_PREFIX:-${HOME}/x-tools}/${CT_HOST:+HOST-${CT_HOST}/}${CT_TARGET}) Prefix directory`
- Hit Enter, delete the contents, and replace it with `/Users/USER/ct-ng-toolchains`. 
- When you’re finished, hit Enter to confirm, scroll over and save, and then exit the configurator.

- Build your toolchain (this may take half an hour):

```sh
ct-ng build
```

- If it worked successfully, You should see a great many binaries now in `/Users/USER/ct-ng-toolchains/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/bin`, namely `armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.
- For cargo to build using your new cross-compiler, you must:

  1. Add the bin folder listed above to your PATH:

```sh
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/USER/ct-ng-toolchains/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/bin"
```

2. Update (or create) your global `/Users/USER/.cargo/config` file with (you can avoid this and use it in local `.cargo/config`):

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```

3.Return to your Rust project and rerun cargo build:

```sh
cd /Users/USER/rust/hello
cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

4. The output should be something similar to:

```sh
   Compiling hello v0.1.0 (file:///Users/USER/rust/hello)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.85 secs
```

5. SCP your file over to the RPi and run the binary remotely:

```sh
scp target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/hello pi@192.168.1.43:
ssh pi@192.168.3.155 'chmod +x ~/hello && ~/hello'
Hello, world!
```

Credit goes to [Kappel Codes](https://akappel.github.io/2017/11/07/rpi-crosstool.html) I tried to summarize it here, as I found this question hours before I get that article :)