# error: linker `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` not found - M1 Mac

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, apple-m1, rust-cargo, crosstool-ng

Trying to cross compile Rust for the Raspberry Pi and running into a lot of issues - I believe I've reduced it down to this 'linker not found' error. Only trouble is, I'm not sure how to go about installing this.

I've started going down the rabbit hole of installing `crosstool-ng` (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896510/13131208)), but this is creating it's own slew of errors relating to not being able to find `objcopy` or `gobjcopy`. I've tried installing these using `brew install binutils` to no avail.

Is this route making my life unneccesarily difficult and I'm missing some easy way to get this running? I figure this would be as simple as

```
rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

and adding

```
[build]
target = "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"

[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc"
```

to my `/.cargo/config` but alas this has proven to be quite cumbersome.

Comment: You said it was cumbersome, but did it work?

Comment: @TimRoberts apologies, should have clarified - after chewing away for a while at installing `gobjcopy` and/or `objcopy` through Homebrew `binutils`, I stopped to write this post to make sure I'm not making my life harder for no particular reason.

Comment: You might be able to use `lld` instead

Comment: So, does that mean "yes, this works"?  Because I think that's the intended path.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have no idea if this works or not - if this is the intended path I'll continue down it. At the moment, I can't get `gobjcopy` or `objcopy` to be recognized after adding it to PATH.

Comment: @PitaJ what is the current way in Rust to link with `lld`? Tried executing with `rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld",]` and received the error `error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1`